# offset or separate axis for multiple xAxis in apache echarts within the same category

Tags: javascript, echarts

I have the code below. I want to separate each bar within each category so they do not overlap. This code is definitely not working as intended. Could you please help to fix the code so I get the desired output?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Apache ECharts - Multiple X-Axes with Separated Bars</title>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.1.2/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>

    <script>
      const xAxisData1 = ["Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3"];
      const xAxisData2 = ["Category A", "Category B", "Category C"];
      const xAxisData3 = ["Category X", "Category Y", "Category Z"];

      const seriesData1 = [100, 200, 150];
      const seriesData2 = [300, 150, 250];
      const seriesData3 = [50, 100, 200];

      const chart = echarts.init(document.getElementById("chart"));

      const options = {
        grid: [
          { left: 50, right: 10 }, // grid for the first x-axis
          { left: 150, right: 10 }, // grid for the second x-axis
          { left: 250, right: 10 }, // grid for the third x-axis
        ],
        xAxis: [
          {
            type: "category",
            data: xAxisData1,
            offset: 0, // no offset for the first x-axis
            axisLine: {
              onZero: false, // show the axis line on the zero position
            },
          },
          {
            type: "category",
            data: xAxisData2,
            offset: 40, // some offset for the second x-axis
            axisLine: {
              onZero: false, // show the axis line on the zero position
            },
          },
          {
            type: "category",
            data: xAxisData3,
            offset: 80, // more offset for the third x-axis
            axisLine: {
              onZero: false, // show the axis line on the zero position
            },
          },
        ],
        yAxis: {},
        series: [
          {
            type: "bar",
            data: seriesData1,
            xAxisIndex: 0,
            barWidth: `${50 / xAxisData1.length}%`,
            barGap: `-100%`,
            barCategoryGap: "20%",
            itemStyle: {
              color: "#c23531", // red color for the first series
            },
          },
          {
            type: "bar",
            data: seriesData2,
            xAxisIndex: 1,
            barWidth: 20, // set the bar width to 20px
            barGap: "10%",
            barCategoryGap: "20%",
            itemStyle: {
              color: "#2f4554", // blue color for the second series
            },
          },
          {
            type: "bar",
            data: seriesData3,
            xAxisIndex: 2,
            barGap: "10%",
            barCategoryGap: "20%",
            itemStyle: {
              color: "#61a0a8", // green color for the third series
            },
          },
        ],
      };

      chart.setOption(options);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The current output?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Apache ECharts - Separated Bars with Equal Distance</title>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.1.2/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>

    <script>
      const categoryData = ["Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3"];
      const categoryDataAlpha = ["Category A", "Category B", "Category C"];
      const categoryDataAlpha2 = ["Category X", "Category Y", "Category Z"];
      const seriesData1 = [100, 200, 150];
      const seriesData2 = [300, 150, 250];
      const seriesData3 = [50, 100, 200];
      const totalCategories = categoryData.length;
      const totalSeries = 3;

      const chart = echarts.init(document.getElementById("chart"));

      const options = {
        grid: {
          containLabel: true,
          left: 50,
          right: 10,
        },
        xAxis: [
          {
            type: "category",
          data: categoryData,
            offset: 0, // some offset for the second x-axis
          axisLine: {
            onZero: false,
          }
        },
        {            
            type: "category",
            data: categoryDataAlpha,
            offset: 40, // some offset for the second x-axis
            axisLine: {
                onZero: false, // show the axis line on the zero position
            }
        },
{            type: "category",
            data: categoryDataAlpha2,
            offset: 80, // some offset for the second x-axis
            axisLine: {
                onZero: false, // show the axis line on the zero position
            }
        },
        ],
        yAxis: {},
        series: [
          {
            type: "bar",
            data: seriesData1,
            barWidth: `${70 / (totalCategories * totalSeries)}%`,
            itemStyle: {
              color: "#c23531", // red color
            },
          },
          {
            type: "bar",
            data: seriesData2,
            barWidth: `${70 / (totalCategories * totalSeries)}%`,
            itemStyle: {
              color: "#2f4554", // blue color
            },
          },
          {
            type: "bar",
            data: seriesData3,
            barWidth: `${70 / (totalCategories * totalSeries)}%`,
            itemStyle: {
              color: "#61a0a8", // green color
            },
          },
        ],
      };

      chart.setOption(options);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried your solution, it did not make any separation between the bars within the same category!

Comment: I edited my solution, try this one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).